# Append table to other DataFrame in JupyterNotebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

I am really new to python programming and the use of jupyter notebooks, so don't bother explain it to me like I'm an idiot.
First I create a table:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', 'EN', 'DE', 'RU', 'FR', 'ES', 'Pos_Neg', 'com'])
```

Then I define a function to write to my tabel:

```
def writeToTable(df_b):
    df_a.append(df_b, ignore_index=True)
```

Later in the programm I call that program (from another cell) an give it another table I generated:

```
writeToTable(df_loop)
```

df_a is created, df_loop is filled and df_b is too, but for some reason df_a is empty, even after the append. Maybe you can help me.

The goal is to loop through the program and expand the df_a table by apending df_loop to it.

Comment: `append` is not in place, you need to return your output, also this method is being deprecated, switch to `concat`

Comment: Yes, you can also directly `return` no need for the variable ;)

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).